# How do I get the value not the text selected.but the value inside < value=something>

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="bethorse">
  <option value="horse1">White</option>
  <option value="horse2">Blue</option>
  <option value="horse3">Green</option>
  <option value="horse4">Brown</option>
</select>
```

S searched but the answers were for the selected text and I used this code `bethorse= document.getElementById('bethorse').value;`.  It gives me number of the position the test. For example value 3 for horse4 just like in array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/4229270

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = document.getElementById("bethorse");
var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

The variable `option` will hold the value of selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working in this example:

```html
<select id="bethorse">
      <option value="horse1">White</option>
      <option value="horse2">Blue</option>
      <option value="horse3">Green</option>
      <option value="horse4">Brown</option>
    </select>

<button onclick="javascript:alert(document.getElementById('bethorse').value);">
    test
</button>
```

Comment: @deceze wow it is working now don't what happened before thanks tho.